# Function App consumes only 8 messages per minute from Service Bus with Sessions Enabled topic

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

We have a Consumption plan Function App which consumes messages from Service Bus via a ServiceBusTrigger (function is v4, .net 6). Despite the processing of messages being almost instantaneous, we consume only 8 messages from Service Bus per minute.

We've raised this with Azure who are being helpful, but also reaching out here as we're confused how others across the world aren't hitting the same issue.

Service bus has a 'MaxConcurrentSessions' configuration with a default setting of 8. This means that if you consume from a subscription with sessions enabled, you would process only 8 messages per minute (which is of course extremely slow).

We're encountering bugs where this setting is not respected even when set - but we're wondering whether others have encountered the same issue? Did people end up giving up on Service Bus sessions entirely, or have people been able to achieve good performance even with the above limit?

Answer (score 1):

The Service Bus SDK package currently used by the trigger has a bug which incorrectly ties concurrency for sessions to a synchronization point for accepting a session.  As a result, processing is only performed concurrently for messages that were available to be read at the time the session was first accepted; any messages arriving after that point do not honor concurrency.

This was fixed yesterday via [#33035](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/pull/33035), but won't be available in a stable package until the next scheduled release window (currently early February).

In the meantime, it may help to lower the `sessionIdleTimeout` value in your [host.json settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp).  The default for `sessionIdleTimeout` is to use the `tryTimeout` which is 60 seconds unless overridden.  Lowering that value would cycle through sessions more rapidly, which should help to improve throughput.

Comment: Thank you for this! I'm not sure this specific bug correlates exactly to what we're seeing - because we see a bunch of 8 messages consumed very quickly, then nothing consumed for the rest of the minute. The above sounds more like it relates to concurrency restrictions, but in our case we see no messages arrive at all after this brief burst (please correct me if I'm mistaken)

Comment: That's a bit different than I originally interpreted what you were saying - so maybe not a clear match.   If there are no more messages available for that particular session, the behavior is expected.  The idle timeout will wait 60 seconds for new messages in a session before moving to the next.    If there are messages for that session available in the subscription while the session is held, you should see them come in 1-by-1 with the bug if you're completing messages.

Comment: If you believe there are messages available in the subscription for the session while it is held, you're completing messages, and you're not seeing anything being received after the initial call - then would you please open an issue in the Azure SDK repository?   We should poke at that more deeply than StackOverflow's format allows for.    (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues)

Comment: Thanks - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/33046